# Most efficient way to store boolean values in Firebase DB

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Basically, I need to know what takes less storage space and traffic - 1/0, "1"/"0" or true/false?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on what platform you're using firebase has written drivers that handle sending the most effecient way when you assign a variable with the type 'boolean'. So just pass a boolean.

Comment: @M0CH1R0N Thanks, so this applies to both storage AND downloading, right? Basically, I will not save any storage space if I change true to 1 in Firebase web interface?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @M0CH1R0N Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most efficient way to store a boolean is **to set the value as a boolean**. That's why Firebase creators offered us this possibility. Storing the value as a boolean offers everything that [Java Boolean Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) offers. It's not a good practice, to use `0` or `1` in stead of a boolean.

Regarding space, yes it's a difference. Try create to 1000 records with `true` and `false`, then create other 1000 record with `0` and `1`, export the JSON file and you see the difference.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that a boolean should really be stored as boolean and nothing else. I thought that maybe Firebase somehow stores booleans as int or something, so there's no difference in storage space either, but you're right, appears there actually is. I tried storing ~250k records as boolean, string and int, and it took 3.3MB, 3.1MB and 2.6MB respectively, so looks like everything is stored as plain text (which was expected for a JSON DB after all).

Comment: one can use `TypeConverter`, in case being worried about export file-sizes.